# Graphlab Date Manipulaiton

Tags: python-2.7, graphlab

I have a `dataset` that I am trying to manipulate in GraphLab. I want to convert a UNIX Epoch timestamp from the input file *(converted to an SFrame)* into a human readable format so I can do analysis based on hour of day and day of week.

time_array is the column/feature of the `SFrame sf` representing the timestamp, I have broken out just the EPOCH time to simplify things. I know how to convert the time of one row, but I want a vector operation. Here is what I have for one row.

```
time_array = sf['timestamp']

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_array[0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get parts of the time from the timestamp to create another column, by which to filter (e.g., get the hour):

```
sf['hour'] = [x.strftime('%H')for x in sf['timestamp']]
```

Answer (score 0):

So after staring at this for awhile and then posting the question it came to me, hopefully someone else can benefit as well. Use the `.apply` method with the `datetime.datetime()` function

```
sf['date_string'] = sf['timestamp'].apply(lambda x:    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'))
```

Comment: You can also get parts of the time from the timestamp to create another column, by which to filter (e.g., get the hour):    sf['hour'] = [x.strftime('%H')for x in sf['timestamp']]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the `split_datetime` API to split the timestamp to multiple columns:

```
split_datetime('timestamp',limit=['hour','minute'])
```